# Python 2 import builtin

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, future, python-2.x

I need to make code compatible for Python2/3 and it uses the dict() builtin, but I can't figure out how to import it from the `__future__` module.

For example,

dict.iteritems() does't exist in Python 3, and likewise dict.items() doesn't exist in Python 2.

Comment: Can you show the code (or some abridged and relevant version) you are trying to work with? As far as I know both versions provide the `dict` built in, so what is the issue? You can do the following from REPL to view all properties of `__future__`'. `import __future__; dir(__future__)`.

Comment: @PaulRooney, I have added an example.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that python 2 does not have a `dict.items` method. It's just different from python3 in that it returns a list rather than a lazy iterator. It's therefore inefficient when used on large dictionaries.

Comment: In python 2 the builtins module is called `__builtin__`. Although I don't think it will help you. There is a python library called six which will give you a portable version. I guess it depends on how much else has to be cross version. It might not be worth a library for just one function call.

Comment: see [this site](http://python-future.org/imports.html#imports-of-builtins). I don't believe its 100% accurate (some things i tried with py2 didn't work, could be a version thing) but you may find something there that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `from __future__ import dict` because Python 2 already has a `dict`. It is true that Python 2's `dict.iteritems()` does more or less what Python 3's `dict.items()` does.

But you are not correct when you say that Python 2 doesn't have `dict.items()`, and there is nothing to stop you using `dict.items()` in both versions.  For all normal purposes they will behave the same.

Typically you use `dict.items()` like this:

```
for k,v in mydict.items():
```

That will work identically in both versions.